# Insert to a table all records from a column from another table with a standard value

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, database

I have two tables, shops and products. Table shop with columns shopId (PK) and shopName. Another table Products has columns productId (PK) and productName. Because I have a relationship many-many between two tables I create another table shopProduct with two columns shopId and productId.

For example I have shop1 with id=1 and I have shop2 with id=2, product1 with id=1 and product2 with id=2. and the records of the table shopProduct is 1-1 ,2-2.

But now I want to have a product3 with id=3 that apply to all shops.

I consider in the real problem that i have about 250 shops.

How can implement this without a stored procedure?

I don't want to do of course 250

```
insert into shopProduct (shopId, productId) 
values (@shopId,@productId).
```

Can I do for loop for example to feed the the shopId value every time?The other value for product id is the same every time.

Comment: Is this a 1 time insert? Or will this be an ongoing process?

Comment: in table shop i have all shops,and in the Product table i have all the products,only in table shopProduct  i want to add the records

Comment: What is the problem inserting the required number of records to maintain a correct relationship between Shops and Products?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding of this question, try this... Seems too simple, but...

```
Insert into ShipProduct (ProductID, ShopID)
Select 3, ShopID
From Shops
```

Comment: Depending on the table they are `insert`ing into, they may also need to set `identity_insert` on

Comment: Good point, but OP didn't give any table schema definition. :-)

Comment: @WEI_DBA thank you very much ! It works, but i would like also to give me a resource about this queries to understand further!

Comment: You can Google of course, but I'll give you the Microsoft Docs version of the `Insert` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017